# Select rows with and without match of join

Tags: postgresql

This – allegedly easy – task currently I cannot solve.

### SQL Fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/90dce/1

### Schema

Given this schema and data

```sql
CREATE TABLE asset (
    "id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IDX_id" ON asset (id);

CREATE TABLE category (
    "id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "ctype" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "name" TEXT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY ("id")
);
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS "IDX_id" ON category (id);

CREATE TABLE asset_category (
    "asset_id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    "category_id" BIGINT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_asset_id" FOREIGN KEY ("asset_id") REFERENCES "asset" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    CONSTRAINT "FK_category_id" FOREIGN KEY ("category_id") REFERENCES "category" ("id") ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    UNIQUE (asset_id, category_id)
);


INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(1, 'Awesome Asset with a hit');
INSERT INTO asset (id, "name") VALUES(2, 'Great Asset without a hit');

INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "ctype") VALUES(1, 'First Category', NULL);
INSERT INTO category (id, "name", "ctype") VALUES(2, 'Second Category', 'directory');

INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(1, 1);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(1, 2);
INSERT INTO asset_category ("asset_id", "category_id") VALUES(2, 1);
```

### Task

I want to get all assets with their category Id (in case they have one of type "directory". Otherwise NULL as category.

See my query below, I wrote two joins letting me limit the results in the `ON` clause. However, since both are related to the other category, the first JOIN hinders me to get a clean result.

### What I tried

This query **Query A**

```sql
SELECT a.id "assetId", c.id "categoryId"
FROM asset a
LEFT JOIN asset_category ac ON ac.asset_id = a.id
left join category c on (
    c.id = ac.category_id
    AND
    c.ctype = 'directory'   
)
```

restulting in:

```
assetId     categoryId
1           (null)
1           2
2           (null)
```

That is almost good, except, assetId 1 appears twice. This probably due to first JOIN, which creates a relation to `assetcategory` and the other category not of type 'directory'. Same as assetId 2.

**Query B** uses inner join:

```sql
SELECT a.id "assetId", c.id "categoryId"
FROM asset a
LEFT JOIN asset_category ac ON ac.asset_id = a.id
inner join category c on (
    c.id = ac.category_id
    AND
    c.ctype = 'directory'   
)
```

resulting in

```
assetId     categoryId
1           2
```

However, here the problem is, it hides asset with id 2 for me as join is not successfully resolving asset id 2.

### Desired output

```
assetId | categoryId
1       | 2
2       | null
```

I would be really happy about this seemingly simple task.

Comment: Can you update your post with the expected output?

Comment: "*I want to query the assets such as I get all of them and in case of an associated category of type 'directory' get this aswell.*" - doesn't look clear what you're attempting to do and where the expected output stems from. Can you provide further explanation?

Comment: Updated, now really bullet-proof, I hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/evyp7rms)

Your first query is a good approach. It seems you wanted only one record per `id`. This is what is `DISTINCT ON` for:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (a.id)
    a.id, c.id
FROM asset a
LEFT JOIN asset_category ac ON a.id = ac.asset_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON c.id = ac.category_id AND c."ctype" = 'directory'
ORDER BY a.id, ctype NULLS LAST
```

So, just order your joined result by `id` first, and order `ctype = NULL` records to bottom, which makes the `directory` values bubble up being the first one. `DISTINCT ON` takes the first record for each `id` afterwards which is the one you expect.

Comment: Thanks for the `NULLS LAST`, this really is crucial